# How to set caret to the last character of Range object in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having hard time figuring out how to set the caret position based on the last character in the Range object.

For instance I have contenteditable which has some text.

```
Hello world Test
```

Then I highlight portion of text ("wor") with mouse:

[image]

Then mouseup event will get selected range.

After focus it gone, the selected highlight will disappear.

Now, my goal is to set the caret to between "r" and "l" like image below (the end of the Range)

[image]

So far I got getting selection and restoring part worked but can't figure out the caret setting based on Range object.

**Code:**

```
var node = this.element.find(".reContentArea")[0];
var range = document.createRange();

var sel = window.getSelection();

sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `focusOffset` to get the character position where the selection ends:

```
$('.reContentArea').on('mouseup', function() {
    var offset= window.getSelection().focusOffset 
})
```

In setting the caret position on a `contenteditable element` we can use [`setStart(startNode, startOffset)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.setStart). As you can see in this method we need to specify the node and the offset within that node.

```
var editable = $('.reContentArea')[0],
    range = document.createRange(),
    sel = window.getSelection();    

range.setStart(editable.firstChild, offset);
range.collapse(true);
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

It's not clear to me what even you want to trigger the "to set the caret to", but I've made a simple click event with this solution on this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/zc8hP/).

Comment: Note that if you need to know the position of the caret in pixels, you may hit bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1398728

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this awesome plugin

https://github.com/acdvorak/jquery.caret

```
// Select everything after the 6th character
$('input').range(6);
$('textarea').val('Hello\nWorld').range(6).range().text === 'World';
```

check demo here :

http://www.examplet.org/jquery/caret.php

Comment: This works on `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements, right? But not on a `contenteditable` element.

Comment: Oh sorry I haven't noticed your response. No, I mean **it's not working on contenteditable element** and I am not asking the question there. Andrew (the creator of jquery.caret) has been in contact with me when he first started the project. There are a lot of complicated issues working with text ranges in DOM - like handling selections spanning multiple elements, line breaks, paragraphs, CSS rules (esp. on IE). So he did not include this feature on the plugin if it can't be handled properly at the moment, as it may present a drawback for this awesome plugin. Cheers!